# How to group rows with same column values?

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping

Given the matrix with coordinates in 3D space and values for two variables (say a and b) in two matrices I would like to merge rows for same points into a common matrix.

To clearly explain the matter, let's say we have matrices

```
A=[posX, posY, posZ, a]
and 
B=[posX, posY, posZ, b]
```

and would like to combine them into

```
AB = [posX, posY, posZ, a, b]
```

for example

```
A = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 4; 5 0 12 8];
B = [0 0 0 5; 0 1 0 3; 5 11 7 7];
```

would give

```
AB = [0 0 0 0 5; 0 0 1 1 0; 0 1 0 4 3; 5 0 12 8 0; 5 11 7 0 7];
```

In order to do that I first created

```
ATemp = [A, zeros(length(A,0)]
```

and

```
BTemp = [B(:, [1 2 3]), zeros(length(B),1), B(:,4)]
```

and then tried to use functions `accumarray` and `grpstats` but haven't managed to form the AB matrix.

I would be very thankful if anyone suggested the way to get the desired matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AB=union(A(:,1:3),B(:,1:3),'rows');
AB(ismember(AB,A(:,1:3),'rows'),4)=A(:,4);
AB(ismember(AB(:,1:3),B(:,1:3),'rows'),5)=B(:,4)
```

[edit] This solution is only valid if each (x,y,z)-point occurs only once in each matrix. If there are several, there is a dimension mismatch in the second line (and/or the third).

Comment: don't you need to get rid of the duplicate rows in AB after the first line?

Comment: @Dan "UNION(A,B,'rows') [...] returns the combined rows from the two matrices with no repetitions" says my MATLAB help. Besides, I checked that my `AB` equals his `AB`, so there apparently was no duplicate for the one element in both `A` and `B`.

Comment: unique(union(A(:,1:3),B(:,1:3),'rows');, 'rows'); will fix the problem you highlight in in your edit?

Comment: @Dan The result of `union` is already unique. To allow repeated coordinates, the problem definition has to be "fixed" first: Which matching row of `A` should be picked for the one in `AB`? Or if there are several in `A` and `B`, which one should be matched with which?