# How to sum values among matrices of structures under certain conditions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, structure

I am new in matlab and I am not familiar with array of matrices. I have a number of matrices nx6:

```
<26x6 double>
<21x6 double>
<27x6 double>
<36x6 double>
<29x6 double>
<30x6 double>
 ....
```

Each matrix is of this type:

```
>> Matrix{1,1}

A   B   C   D    E                  F
1   2   6   223  735064.287500000   F11
2   3   6   223  735064.288194445   F12
3   4   6   223  735064.288888889   F13
4   5   6   223  735064.290277778   F14

>> Matrix{2,1}

A   B   C   D    E                  F
1   2   6   223  735064.700694445   F21
2   3   6   223  735064.701388889   F22
3   4   6   223  735064.702083333   F23
4   5   6   223  735064.702777778   F24

>> Matrix{3,1}

A   B   C   D    E                  F
1   2   7   86  735064.3541666666   F31
2   3   7   86  735064.3548611112   F32
3   4   7   86  735064.3555555555   F33
4   5   7   86  735064.3562499999   F34
5   6   7   86  735064.702777778    F35

>> Matrix{4,1}

A   B   C   D    E                  F
1   2   7   86   735064.3569444444  F41
2   3   7   86   735064.3576388888  F42
3   4   7   86   735064.3583333333  F43
4   5   7   86   735064.3590277778  F44
5   6   6   86   735064.702777778   F45
```

Where E and F are dates in `datenum` format. Specifically F is the time difference.

Considering all matrices at once, I would like to sum the values of column F among all the matrices that have equal values in columns A, B, D.

For each value of the column D (the number of bus), I would like to obtain a new matrix like the following one:

```
A   B   C   D    H
1   2   6   223  F11+F21
2   3   6   223  F12+F22
3   4   6   223  F13+F23
4   5   6   223  F14+F24


A   B   C   D   H
1   2   7   86  F31+F41
2   3   7   86  F32+F42
3   4   7   86  F33+F43
4   5   7   86  F34+F44
5   6   7   86  F35+F45
```

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How group sums by multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982693/how-group-sums-by-multiple-columns). also [how to group rpws with same column values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980104/how-to-group-rows-with-same-column-values) and several others... search for "[matlab] grouping"

Comment: @Shai: the second link is an example with two equal size matrices so a different case. Could you please let me know if there are other examples similar to my case? Thank you in advance

Comment: update: this works [~,ind]=unique(matrix{i,1},'rows') but it creates an index only yo the column A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach should get you started. I suggested setting up a matrix that stores the comparison between the columns 1,2 and 4. Based on that matrix you can then generate your output matrix. This saves you nested `if` statements and checks in your loop.
Here's an example (please note that I changed row 3 of `Matrix{1,1}`):

```
Matrix{1,1} = [ ...

1   2   6   223  735064.287500000   1;
2   3   6   223  735064.288194445   2;
3   4   6   223  735064.288888889   3;
4   5   6   223  735064.290277778   4];

Matrix{2,1} = [ ...

1   2   6   223  735064.700694445   10;
2   3   6   223  735064.701388889   10;
2   4   6   223  735064.702083333   10;
4   5   6   223  735064.702777778   10];

COMP = Matrix{1,1}(:,[1:2 4])==Matrix{2,1}(:,[1:2 4]);

a = 1;

for i=1:size(Matrix{1,1},1)
    if sum(COMP(i,:)) == 3
        SUM{1,1}(a,1:5) = Matrix{1,1}(i,1:5);
        SUM{1,1}(a,6) = Matrix{1,1}(i,6) + Matrix{2,1}(i,6);
        a = a + 1;
    end
end
```

The matrix `COMP` stores a `1` for each element that is the same in `Matrix{1,1}` and `Matrix{2,1}` when comparing columns 1, 2 and 4.
This reduces the `if`-statement to a check if all elements in a row agree (hence `sum == 3`). If that condition is satisfied, a new matrix is generated (`SUM{1,1}`) which sums the entries in column 6, in this case:

```
 SUM{1,1}(:,6) = 

     11
     12
     14
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, the example is working and I am working to adapt it to my case. I believe that COMP should be an array of matrices of 1 or 0.